# How to get textbox value from jquery datatables when I click the update button of that row

Tags: javascript, jquery

At, first datatables load, then update the qty, then I click the update buttton. I want to get the updated qty textbox value.

```
 $('#dataList').dataTable({ 
    "ajax": url + "Sales/SalesTempList",
    "columns": [
        { "data": "Barcode" },
        { "data": "ProdcutDescription" },
        { "data": "RPU" },
        {
            "mData": null,
            "bSortable": false,
            "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                return '<input type="text" id="' + data.Barcode + '" value="' + data.Sqty + '" class="form-control" />';
            }
        },
        { "data": "Total" },
        {
            "mData": null,
            "bSortable": false,
            "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                return '<button type="button" onclick="LoadForUpdate(\'' + data.TempId + '\');" class="btn btn-xs btn-info"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>' +
                '&nbsp;&nbsp; <button type="button" onclick="LoadForDelete(\'' + data.TempId + '\');" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>';
            }
        }
    ]
});


 function LoadForUpdate(parameters) {
  // need the textbox cell value of edited row when I click the update button of this row
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to "find" the `input`  when you click on the `button` so you just need to add `this` keyword to the `onclick` function:

```
onclick="LoadForUpdate(this/* add here */, \'' + data.TempId + '\');
```

So in the function `LoadForUpdate` you will get the instance of the button. Then you "go" to his `tr` parent and find the input.

```js
 $('#dataList').dataTable({ 
    "ajax": url + "Sales/SalesTempList",
    "columns": [
        { "data": "Barcode" },
        { "data": "ProdcutDescription" },
        { "data": "RPU" },
        {
            "mData": null,
            "bSortable": false,
            "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                return '<input type="text" id="' + data.Barcode + '" value="' + data.Sqty + '" class="form-control" />';
            }
        },
        { "data": "Total" },
        {
            "mData": null,
            "bSortable": false,
            "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                return '<button type="button" onclick="LoadForUpdate(this, \'' + data.TempId + '\');" class="btn btn-xs btn-info"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>' +
                '&nbsp;&nbsp; <button type="button" onclick="LoadForDelete(\'' + data.TempId + '\');" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>';
            }
        }
    ]
});


 function LoadForUpdate(btn, parameters) {
  var val = $(btn).parents('tr').first().find('input').val();
 }
```